# Optimizing this NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, optimization, nspredicate

I'm using an `NSPredicate` to search an array of `NSManagedObject` instances. Each "article" has a "title", a "content", and is potentially matched up with several "tags".

I want to use a regex to match the content of the articles, and another search operator is just fine for everything else. The problem is that my search is dreadfully slow as is. Here's what I've got:

```
- (void) filterArrayWithSearchTerm:(NSString *)searchString andScopeIndex:(NSInteger)scopeIndex{

//
//  Grab a local copy of the search string.
//  This is done simply for convenience in the
//  following set of if statements.
//

NSMutableString *modifiedSearchString = [searchString mutableCopy];
NSPredicate *predicate;

//1 is "content" and 3 is "all" 
if(scopeIndex == 1 || scopeIndex == 3){

    NSInteger length = [searchString length];

    NSString *vowelsAsRegex = @"[\u0591-\u05c4]?[\u0591-\u05c4]?";

    //If our search includes the body of the text

    for (int i = length; i > 0; i--) {
        [modifiedSearchString insertString:vowelsAsRegex atIndex:i];
    }

    [modifiedSearchString insertString:@".*" atIndex:0];
    [modifiedSearchString appendString:@".*"];
}

//
//  Depending on the selected scope bar option 
//  we perform a "MATCHES" search. 
//  
//  For searching properties of related entities, we use the ANY keyword
//

//NSLog(@"Regex: %@", modifiedSearchString);

if (scopeIndex == 0) {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@", modifiedSearchString];
}else if (scopeIndex == 1) {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleContent CONTAINS[cd] %@", modifiedSearchString];            
}else if (scopeIndex == 2){
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.tagText MATCHES[cd] %@", modifiedSearchString];
}else{
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY tags.tagText CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (articleTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (articleContent MATCHES[cd] %@)", modifiedSearchString, modifiedSearchString, modifiedSearchString];
}

[modifiedSearchString release];

NSMutableArray *unfilteredResults = [[[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0] objects] mutableCopy];

//
//  Ensure that we have an array to work with.
//

if (self.filteredArray == nil) {
    self.filteredArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc ] init] autorelease];
}

//
//  Clear out any existing objects from earlier.
//

[filteredArray removeAllObjects];


//
//  Perform the filtering by looping
//  through the articles and checking
//  it against the predicate.
//

for (Article *article in unfilteredResults) {

    if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:article])
        [self.filteredArray addObject:article];

}
//
//  Release the unfiltered array.
//

[unfilteredResults release];
}
```

What optimizations can be applied to make this searching faster?

**Edit:**

I've stripped down my code a little, removing an extra array the comments. I'm specifically asking about optimizing my NSPredicate "contains" and "Matches" to see if there's a faster way to implement them. Here's the new code:

```
- (void) filterArrayWithSearchTerm:(NSString *)searchString andScopeIndex:(NSInteger)scopeIndex{


NSMutableString *modifiedSearchString = [searchString mutableCopy];
NSPredicate *predicate;

if(scopeIndex == 1 || scopeIndex == 3){

    NSInteger length = [searchString length];

    NSString *vowelsAsRegex = @"[\u0591-\u05c4]?[\u0591-\u05c4]?"; //Trop: \u0591-\u05AF Nekudot: \u05b0-\u05c

    for (int i = length; i > 0; i--) {
        [modifiedSearchString insertString:vowelsAsRegex atIndex:i];
    }

    [modifiedSearchString insertString:@".*" atIndex:0];
    [modifiedSearchString appendString:@".*"];
}

if (scopeIndex == 0) {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@", modifiedSearchString];
}else if (scopeIndex == 1) {
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleContent CONTAINS[cd] %@", modifiedSearchString];            
}else if (scopeIndex == 2){
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.tagText MATCHES[cd] %@", modifiedSearchString];
}else{
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY tags.tagText CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (articleTitle CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (articleContent MATCHES[cd] %@)", modifiedSearchString, modifiedSearchString, modifiedSearchString];
}

[modifiedSearchString release];

NSMutableArray *unfilteredResults = [[[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0] objects] mutableCopy];

[unfilteredResults filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
self.filteredArray = unfilteredResults;

[unfilteredResults release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
NSString *vowelsAsRegex = @"[\u0591-\u05c4]?[\u0591-\u05c4]?";
```

should be equal to this one:

```
NSString *vowelsAsRegex = @"[\u0591-\u05c4]{0,2}";
```

That ought to reduce the number of branches in the RegEx matching, but tbh, I don't know.

Comment: This is likely the best solution, but it appears that I need further optimization, beyond the regex.

Answer (score 1):

append; rather than doing a lot of inserts:

```
NSMutableString *modifiedSearchString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

if(scopeIndex == 1 || scopeIndex == 3)
{

    NSString *vowelsAsRegex = @"[\u0591-\u05c4]?[\u0591-\u05c4]?";

    [modifiedSearchString appendString:@".*"];

    for (int i = 0, length = [searchString length]; i < l; i++)
    {
        [modifiedSearchString appendString:vowelsAsRegex];
        [modifiedSearchString appendString:[searchString characterAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [modifiedSearchString appendString:@".*"];
}
```